# CSS won't recognise hover state

Tags: css, image, button, hover, submit

I have the following in my css:

```
.myclasss:hover {
background: url("images/arw_flogin2.png")  no-repeat; border: none;
display: block;
width: 90px;
height: 50px;

}
```

and the following in my HTML:

```
<input type="image" title="" class="myclasss" src="images/arw_flogin1.jpg" />
```

If i change input type to submit it works but not when as image.

Comment: You really should use a more descriptive name than `myclasss`. It'll save you a lot of debugging in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a background image in the non hover state.  Use the following css along with an input of `type="submit"`

**CSS**

```
.myclasss {
    background: url("images/arw_flogin1.png")  no-repeat; border: none;
    display: block;
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;

}

.myclasss:hover {
    background: url("images/arw_flogin2.png")  no-repeat; border: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" class="myclasss" value="" />
```

When you use an input with type image, the image that you have set in the `src` attribute will be applied to the foreground.  Therefore when you change the background on hover you won't see it because the `src` image is still there on the foreground.

Comment: Ok I have that in my css and the following html:  '<input type="submit" title="" class="myclasss" src="images/arw_flogin1.jpg" />'  Yet what I have is a "submit" text (hover works) but no pre-state button.

Comment: I now have a submit text instead of the background image

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I have the background image but it overlaid with the text "submit"

Comment: I added a small update for the html.  The value attribute of a submit button controls what text is displayed.  Setting it to an empty string will get rid of the text.

Comment: Thanks, the submit text was removed with:    text-indent: -9999px; also setting it to an empty string worked !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the SRC of the **input** tag is laid **on top** of the background.

Jrod's method will work, or you can combine the flogin1/2 images and use **background-position: 0 90px** to improve loading times.